# How to shutdown gracefully with Reactor schedulers?

Tags: java, scheduler, project-reactor, graceful-shutdown

Unlike `ExecutorService` with `awaitTermination()`, `dispose()` in Scheduler in Reactor just invokes `shutdownNow()` when disposing; so how to shutdown Scheduler gracefully?

Sometimes we want to terminate our executorService with all submitted tasks completed:

```
// in java
executorService.shutdown();
int  retry =3; 
while(executorService.isTerminated() && retry-- >0){
    executorService.awaitTermination(3, TimieUnit.SECONDS);
}
if(!executorService.isTerminated()){
    executorService.shutdownNow();
}
```

As a rookie in Reactor, the only way for me to shutdown scheduler is invoking `Scheduler.dispose()`. But it seems that implements for Scheduler, such as `Scheduler.BoundedElasticScheduler`,
just invokes `executor.shutdownNow()` to interrupt the inner workers, and ignore the state of submitted tasks. How can I gracefully shutdown the Scheduler until all the tasks complete?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you have with `dispose()`? What are you trying to do or what is the issue? Please [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which shows the problem you have and how/when you want to shutdown the schedulers you are using.

Comment: thanks，question  has been replenished just now @Progman